# How to rotate an image in a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uibutton, image-rotation

I've got a UIButton with an image inside and I want to rotate the image every time you tap. How can I do that? I was thinking that I could use a conditional with a different image every time you tap inside. Is there a method to rotate images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the matrix of the image.  I would start by using UIView animateWithDuration for that.

See CGAffineTransformMakeRotation